# Not sure why case gives error?

Tags: cases

I am trying to write a case:

```
\begin{equation}
    D(i) = 
    \begin{cases}
    False & \text{if } D(j_1) \land D(j_2) \and ... \forall j \in D(i).child \\
    True
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

However, Latex keeps giving the errors: 
`Missing \right. inserted.`, `Display math should end with $$`, `LaTeX Error: \begin{equation} on input line 6 ended by \end{tabular}.`, `Missing $ inserted.`. Not sure why?

I am using these packages:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete MWE which we can run to replicate the error.

Comment: Please merge both code framgmenrs to one small but comple and compilable document, which we can test as it is. Where is defined `\and`? Is `cases complete? mentioned errors can not be produced with showed code fragment.

Comment: `\and` is certainly out of place there, obviously a typo for `\land`.

Answer (score 2):

- it is not clear what you like to present with `cases` (in it is missing condition for second line)
- mentioned errors are not caused with showed code
- instead undefined `\and` probably should be `\land`

I guess, that you probably looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
D(i) =  \begin{cases*}
    \text{False} & if $D(j_1) \land D(j_2) \land \dots\quad\forall j \in D(i).\mathrm{child}$ \\
    \text{True}  & otherwise
        \end{cases*}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]